# Django admin - управление настройками сайта (КАК?)

Tags: python, django

Стоит задача управлять контентом (например надпись в шапке) через админ панель Django. +должна быть возможность мультиязычности.

Как управлять моделями я уже понял, но как как создать форму для управления контентом.

Перешерстил весь интернет, ничего не нашел. Выручайте, коллеги!

Comment: Создать модель с настройками, очевидно же)

Comment: Спасибо, @andreymal! А не мог ли бы вы мне подкинуть материальчик?

Comment: Кстати, для вашей задачи обычные i18n и gettext точно не подходят?

Comment: Я так понимаю в данном случае текст берется с файлов локализации, а мне нужно управлять этим через админ панель, а не править файлы :)

Comment: Можно ещё django-cms попробовать, она такое из коробки умеет. Но настраивается очень нетривиально, не для новичков я бы сказал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в своих проектах делаю примерно так.

**Шаг нулевой: определяемся со списком поддерживаемых языков**

Если арабский, японский и прочую экзотику поддерживать не надо, то можно прописать в настройках список языков, которые будут работать на сайте:

```
# settings.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
]
```

По умолчанию в настройке `LANGUAGES` прописаны все доступные в Django языки, так что если ограничивать ничего не хочется, то настройки можно не менять.

**Шаг первый: создаём модель для хранения настроек**

```
# models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class WebsiteSettings(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, verbose_name=_('Language'))
    some_text = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Some text'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('website settings')
        verbose_name_plural = _('website settings')
        ordering = ['language']

    def __str__(self):
        return dict(settings.LANGUAGES).get(self.language, self.language)
```

Вся соль в поле `language`: у каждого языка свой собственный и единственный экземпляр `WebsiteSettings`. Все остальные поля прописываются на свой вкус по надобности. Миграции, админка и прочая дребедень делаются так же, как и для любой другой модели.

**Шаг второй: пихаем настройки в шаблоны**

Шапка, как правило, бывает на каждой странице, но каждый раз доставать настройки в каждой вьюхе неудобно, так что мы пропишем получение настроек в `context_processors`.

Создаём такой файл `context_processors.py` (или дописываем существующий):

```
from .models import WebsiteSettings

def website_settings(request):
    web_settings = WebsiteSettings.objects.filter(language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE).first()
    if not web_settings:
        web_settings = WebsiteSettings(language='fallback')
    return {'web_settings': web_settings}
```

И включаем это в настройках:

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ... все остальные параметры ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ... все остальные параметры ...
                'имяприложения.context_processors.website_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Теперь в каждом шаблоне будет объект `web_settings` для текущего языка, к полям которого можно обращаться примерно так:

```
{{ web_settings.some_text }}
```

Как Django выбирает текущий язык, читайте где-нибудь в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#implementation-notes). И `LocaleMiddleware` включить не забудьте.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробное описание. Мне это очень помогло.
Но есть один недостаток. Ведь я могу добавить сколько угодно записей например для русского языка. Тогда будет не совсем понятно какая из них будет отображаться на странице. Я думаю было бы правильнее сделать например так:
Раздел "Шапка" > вкладки(группы) "En", "Ru"... > Заголовок, подзаголовок....
Но вот как??)

Comment: «сколько угодно записей например для русского языка» — не понял, там стоит `unique=True` и создать несколько настроек для русского языка админка не даст. Если хочется не мешать все настройки в кучу, то ничего не мешает создать по аналогии модели типа «ShapkaSettings», «PodvalSettings» и так далее)

Comment: блин. Точно! Ты Бог))
Скажи напоследок, есть ли другие способы это сделать? В каком направлении мне стоит погуглить? Это просто для саморазвития, так как с django знаком недавно

Comment: Не знаю, меня и это вполне устраивает и других способов я не искал) Можно разве что предложить хранить все настройки в единственном json-поле единственной модели, а в админке нарисовать красивый виджет со всякими разделами для управления этим json-полем, но для «с django знаком недавно» это будет сложно

Comment: Хорошо. А если я хочу языки добавлять тоже через админку. Как мне это сделать? Я вот создал модель для языков, но что мне теперь нужно подставить вместо `choices=settings.LANGUAGES`

Comment: По умолчанию в этом списке (если `LANGUAGES` из настроек стереть) почти сотня языков, неужто не хватает? Но если всё-таки не хватает, то, как правильно добавлять языки не входящие в эту сотню, я не знаю