# Как правильно добавить модель конфигов сайта в админке Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

Есть ряд уникальных параметров, они должны устанавливаться в админке. Например, api ключи различных сервисов, реквизиты кошельков для оплаты и тп. Первое что пришло на ум это создание OneToOne модели, привязанной к администратору. Однако админов мб несколько, а информация уникальна, т.е. должна занимать ровно 1 запись в бд. 2 Мысль что меня посетила это при добавлении новой записи удалять старую, однако, как мне кажется, это весьма коряво и может запутать пользователя, в следствии чего он может потерять апи ключи. 
Собственно как можно сделать по уму? Есть ли способ ограничить количество записей для конкретной таблицы?

Comment: Что-то я не понял, почему мы вам не завести модель, в полях которой просто взять и прописать все редактируемые параметры? Примерно как я тут делал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637267/178213 только без языков если вам не надо

Comment: А что помешает пользователю создать еще 1 запись?

Comment: Можно убрать кнопку добавления записи :D Готовые решения для подобного уже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как то так:

```
class Config(models.Model):  

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    description = models.TextField()
```

Поле `name` будет уникальным, не получится добавить новую запись с этим же названием. Если нужна более гибкая проверка, можно перегрузить метод `save` и проверять там перед сохранением.
Так же если все настройки известны заранее, лучше их вынести в отдельный список и добавить в `choices` у поля `name`.